# Autoencoder and SVD: Matrix apllications

Tags: python, matrix, autoencoder, svd

in my study, I am using the so-called Lee Carter Model (Mortality model) in which you can get the model parameters by using Singular Values Decomposition on the matrix of (log mortality rate- the average age-specific pattern of mortality).
I am trying to find a substitution of Singular Value Decomposition, I saw that a good choice could be an autoencoding applied by a Recurrent Neural network. In fact, an SVD could be converging to autoencoder in which the activation function is a linear function. At this purpose, I would try using a nonlinear activation function in order to obtain the same items obtained by SVD  with a nonlinear shape. 
Let's use this steps in order to obtain data: mortality rates for ages and years

```
rm(list = ls())

library(MortalitySmooth)

ages <- 0:100

years <- 1960:2009

D <- as.matrix(selectHMDdata("Japan", "Deaths",
                             "Females", ages,
                             years))

D[D==0] <- 1

E <- as.matrix(selectHMDdata("Japan", "Exposures",
                             "Females", ages,
                             years))

E[E==0] <- 1


lMX <- log(D/E)

alpha <- apply(lMX, 1, mean)`

cent.logMXMatrix <- sweep(lMX, 1, alpha)
```

Now we apply SVD on cent.logMXMatrix
when I use SVD in R I get this:

```
SVD <- svd(cent.logMXMatrix)
```

and I need to get the components of SVD:

```
SVD$d
SVD$v
SVD$u
```

I would like to get SVD component using Autoencoder...Is it possible? 
I would like to get your opinion, some suggestion from you and whether is possible I need a basic python code formulation for autoencoder on the "cent.logMXMatrix"

Thank a lot,
Andrea

Comment: SVD is a linear algebra problem. You can use a pseudo autoencoder with just 2 linear layers to get it, of course.

Comment: Thanks, can you show me?

Answer (score 1):

A one-layer autoencoder linearly maps a datapoint to a low-dimensional latent space, then applies a non-linear activation to project the result to the original space while minimizing a reconstruction error. 
If we replace the non-linear activation by a linear one (identity) and use the L2 norm as a reconstruction error, you will be performing the same operation as an SVD.

```
# use keras with tensorflow backend
# This is a vanilla autoencoder with one hidden layer
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model

input_dim = Input(shape = (nfeat, )) # nfeat=the number of initial features
encoded1 = Dense(layer_size1, activation='linear')(input_dim) # layer_size1:size of your encoding layer
decoded1 = Dense(nfeat, activation='linear')
autoencoder = Model(inputs = input_dim, outputs = decoded1)
autoencoder.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
```

Comment: No need for more layers in a linear encoder. But thanks for showing the code for OP. Even here, you should have only 2 layers, not three. Which is why I'm not up voting.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher You're right. Since we have linear activation, no need to add more layers. Sorry for this !

Comment: Thanks for fixing this!